# How to pass control from local machine to Virtual machine through any scripting language?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to build a selenium(Java) script where it connects to virtual machine through RDP from local machine and I need to run some commands from current script in virtual machine after connecting to it. The problem I am facing is that control from local machine is not going into virtual machine because of which I am not able to run any scripts or commands in it.Please let me know how to pass control from local machine to virtual machine.To be more specific will my selenium script which is running in my local machine be able to perform any operations in the virtual machine which is opened by same selenium script running in local machine.

Comment: Instead of keeping selenium in local and connecting to Virtual machine, can we have the complete setup in Virtual machine directly?

Comment: Can you explain the script in details?

Comment: I want a selenium script which automatically checks out a virtual machine(VD) and connect to the IP address through RDP and launch jenkins slave node in virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your VM is linux, you can take a control by using jcraft.

Note: You should have SSH enabled and local IP access to 22 port in VM.

1. Download jcraft from maven central repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch

   ```
   public class ssh {

       /**
        * JSch Example Tutorial
        * Java SSH Connection Program
        */
       @Test
       public static void connection(String host,String user, String password, String command) {

           try{

          java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
               config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
               JSch jsch = new JSch();
               Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
               session.setPassword(password);
               session.setConfig(config);
               session.connect();
               System.out.println("Connected");

               Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
               ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
               channel.setInputStream(null);
               ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
               InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
               channel.connect();
               byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
               while(true){
                 while(in.available()>0){
                   int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                   if(i<0)break;
                   System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                 }
                 if(channel.isClosed()){
                   System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                   break;
                 }
                 try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
               }
               channel.run();
               channel.disconnect();
               session.disconnect();
               System.out.println("DONE");

           }catch(Exception e){

           }

       }

   }
   ```

   2. Connect your VM by providing Host address of your server, username, password, and command you want to execute in it.

      (Ex)

      ```
      public class start{
      static WebDriver driver;
          public static void main(String[], args)
          {
          //connect your VM by using method from ssh class
        ssh.connection("10.200.10.1", "userName", "password", "sudo service jenkins start");
          //execute selenium command once application started
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='usr']")).sendKeys("Stack");
           //execute another command inside VM
      ssh.connection("10.200.10.1", "userName", "password", "cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace && ls");
          }
      }
      ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir.But my virtual machine is Windows server 2008/2016 machines. Can you please let me know how to execute above in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible. your script may invoke RDP protocol to invoke VM but VM is the separate instance it has it own kernel and user space. The script you run will be in different kernel and user space. Both are not shared the same kernel and user space to access the value between the spaces.